# Get the width and height of an image

Tags: php

How can I get the width and height of image? The image url is saved into a variable.
Thank you.

Comment: Googling "PHP image width and height" turns up this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Reference:  [Image processing libraries in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).